# What is a word to describe the state of singularity?

Tags: writing, speech, science

When we have reached as far back into some history as we can theoretically go, like for instance in describing the precise theoretical moment when time began we have reached a singularity.

Is there a word to describe that state?

It seems like the obvious answer is 'singular'.  To us it in a sentence I might say:

> The moment when time began is the singular moment in history.

My question is two-fold:

1. Would this be the correct use of the word singular?
2. Is their another word I could use instead of singular?

**Edit**

Based on the comments below it would appear that the answer to my first question is no. I will amend my example sentence to be:

The moment time began is the **____** moment in history.

So my question is what is the best word to fill in the blank?

Another example that describes the concept that I am looking for would be a train moving from a complete stop. There is a precise moment when a train begins to move, though most often we describe that moment in terms of two distinct states when it was moving and when it was still. I am looking for the word to describe the moment when the movement began. I know that it is an infinitely dense moment and that is described by singularity. I am looking for the tense of that word, singularity,  that completes the sentence.

Comment: ***singularity*** here is a highly context-specific usage *(Astron. A region in space-time at which matter is infinitely dense)* deriving from the also context-specific sense *Math. A point at which a function takes an infinite value*. You probably can't usefully force other forms such as ***singular*** to have any relevance to those meanings. For example, there could have been many ***singular** moments in history*, but there's really only been one ***singularity** so far.

Comment: @FumbleFingers According to my daughter who has a PhD in maths, there are many different infinities. If that be the case, reason suggests to me that there cannot be just one singularity. But what would I know?

Comment: @WS2 I think what fumblefingers means is that there has been only one singularity as narrowly defined in my question, ie the very first moment, in time. Does your daughter have anything that could help answer my question?

Comment: @Thomas Then that's not **the** singularity. That's **a** singularity. Are you asking how to refer to the origin of time, or how to refer to **a** singularity?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I am asking for the word to describe the state of singularity. The origin of time was just a common example of singularity.

Comment: @Thomas Then you've got the two words that define the state of singularity: singular and infinite. Your sentence can't be "The moment when time began is the singular moment in history." because there is (perhaps paradoxically) more than one singular moment in history. You could say "The moment when time began is *a* singular moment in history.", or you could be more specific about what you want to say.

Comment: @KevinWorkman So you seem to be suggesting that the answer to my first question is: no it is not the correct use of the word singular. What would be a better word to complete the sentence? The moment time began is the _________ moment in history?

Comment: @Thomas I fear she would probably respond by asking something like 'What do you mean exactly by 'time'? In short I don't understand these things well enough confidently to ask the question.

Comment: I must be missing something. Why are you looking for an adjective? You have *the* perfect word to describe the state of singularity: *singularity*. Just use it. That is the only word that will do the job reliably, or at all. Everything else will be different, or ambiguous, or not established enough, or all of that at once.

Comment: @RegDwight To be clear you are suggesting that the sentence should read: The moment that time began is the singularity moment in history?

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165048/is-there-a-word-to-describe-the-state-of-being-the-only-one-of-something/165049#165049

Comment: @WS2: One usage I feel is closely related to OP's is the [hypothetical?] impending [***technological singularity**.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity) (first thus described in 1958). I rather doubt *that* one is particularly based on "infinity" in the minds of most speakers. The only real relevance of infinity to these usages is that *we can't understand them*, just as we can't easily manipulate infinite values in maths (all we seem to know so far is there are different *kinds* of mathematical infinities).

Comment: @ Thomas: Virtually by definition, *the* "singularity" identifies an [event?] that human knowledge as yet cannot encompass. So if you have some context where you want to adjectivally refer to it, I think you need to define *what specific attribute of the singularity you want to invoke*. Which seems a bit hopeless, since we know nothing about it. As things stand, I think it's Unclear What You're Asking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'll take your word for it! Unless it involves debit and credit I fear I have little to offer in the field of mathematics.

Comment: @WS2: Your daughter (and people like Peter Shor here, obviously) will know much more about such things than either of us. All I'm really saying is that at the level of *English language* we can't just say *the **singularity** was a **singular** moment in history*. Leaving aside the inappropriate use of "moment" and "history" in such a context, the normal meaning of ***singular*** is just too "commonplace" for the concept. OP needs to narrow down what ***aspect*** of the moment of the Big Bang he's interested in invoking, as distinct from its ineffable "singularityness".

Comment: Avoid *singularity* just say *unique.*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific technical term, which is already precisely defined. Proofreading this is not on topic.

Comment: @RoryAlsop how could this possibly be off topic? It is about a word in the English language, and its proper use. Sure sounds like English and Usage to me.

Comment: This 'proper use' is not down to English - you'd really want a technical glossary for Physics/Astrophysics or similar discipline. If it was a more common word I'd say it should be on ELL or even too simple (get it from a dictionary). I'd definitely call it off topic here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop You have missed the point of the question. The question was not about AstroPhysics or Physics, that was just an example of the word usage. Singularity could definitely be used in other contexts, especially as a rhetorically compelling device; as in 'Only in singularity could the point have been made more precisely.'

Comment: Just a thought, what about: The moment time began is **the unrepeatable moment** in history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you might be looking for something a bit more

> original

It works because of the root: origin, which has basic implication of source, and beginning. Because the question asks about *as far back as we can theoretically go*:

> The moment when time began is the **original** moment in history.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is one of semantics as much as anything. Since "the moment when time began" is an artificial concept, it's difficult to be sure what it is you'd like to say about it!

If we are just to fill in the gaps, I could say

*The moment time began is the **first** moment in history.* :)

Joking aside, as another serious suggestion is *seminal*.

Comment: Seminal may be the best suggestion yet. I want to see if anyone comes up with something better, before I mark that as answered, because it is still not perfect.

Comment: Please provide a bit more than just quoting a word: explain why that word works. Stack Exchange likes complete answers which don't require more research on the part of the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you're looking for `unique`? A unique moment in history--there were no other moments in history like it.

Comment: See the edit. I don't think that unique fits.

Comment: *Every* moment in history is in itself unique.

Answer (score 0):

*Quintessential* should satisfy your need to describe that moment in history. In this case it would be used to convey that this event was the most major turning point to exist.

Speaker: "The moment when time began was the most quintessential time in history."

**Quintessential:**

> representing the most perfect or typical example of a quality or class.

Comment: Quintessential sure sounds good, though I don't think that it is the correct word, quintessential implies a statement of quality or soundness.  I am asking for a word to describe a state of being not a description of fitness for some purpose.

Comment: @Thomas Oh, understood. You're not looking to describe the event itself in terms of history, but the essence of 'beginning' that it is. Thanks for the clarity =).