# Noun for unique thing

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What can I call a thing that is one-of-a-kind?

> This restaurant's Loganberry Duck is one-of-a-kind, and the Crystal Brush Pulpo is another _______.

I want to use it to compliment a dish, to express the "you can only get this here" kind of meaning.

Comment: [Sui generis?](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sui-generis)

Comment: I don't think there IS a one-word *noun* to reference something which can be physically instantiated many times (consecutively *and* concurrently), but ***only from one source***. It's a *very* restricted context, which I'm sure we'd normally describe adjectivally as OP has already done - their Loganberry Duck is *"**one-of-a-kind**", **unique** to that restaurant, a **house specialty,...***

Comment: @FumbleFingers can you think of a noun for something which can be physically instantiated only once?

Comment: [*The **most** wonderful thing about Tiggers ... is **I'm the only one**!*](https://pooh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wonderful_Thing_About_Tiggers)

Comment: Not everyone would accept the rare noun usage, but I'm quite prepared to defend the statement ***Tigger is a uniquity***. (We can't call him a ***singularity***, because theoretical physicists already have dibs on that one! :)

Comment: Why bother looking for another word? Put the full stop after *another*, the sentence reads just fine and expresses the desired meaning. The sentence says that the *Loganberry Duck is one of a kind* and that *the Crystal Brush Pulpo is one of a kind too*, no need to repeat the phrase *one of a kind*. By all means follow @FumbleFingers advice and describe the *Pulpo* as a *uniquity* but that will either have the reader reaching for a dictionary, or deciding that it is a misprint for *iniqutiy* which is perhaps not what the author intends to express.

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a word to describe the state of being the only one of something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165048/is-there-a-word-to-describe-the-state-of-being-the-only-one-of-something/165053#165053). 'Singleton' is given as an answer (though it is more appropriate here).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in my world [singleton](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/singleton) means something quite different to this usage, where I would take it to mean "there is only one portion".

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: There's something a bit quirky about saying ***X** is a ["Tigger" / singularity / one-of-a-kind / ...] and **Y is another** [one of them]*. I'm sure Tigger himself would have been even more [frabjous](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/frabjous) if he'd ever met ***another*** of his kind (especially if it was a ***Mrs** Tigger!)* But as I understand it, by the Pauli Exclusion Principle, that was never gonna happen!

Comment: @Weather Vane Are words restricted to single senses in your world? Yes, I'd not use it with OP's example either, but the question _is_ a near-duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth my apologies, I thought you [wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609818/noun-for-unique-thing?noredirect=1#comment1542852_609818) that 'singleton' *would* be an appropriate answer here. Obviously many words do have more than one sense, but I can't see how that applies to 'singleton' in this usage. If I heard it used in "Our duck is a singleton", I would take to mean they only have a single serving on this occasion.

Comment: The answer at the previous thread I mention obviously aims to answer this question rather than the one there (a 'uniquity' rather than _uniqueness_). 'Singleton' carries the relevant subsense required here, but this is too far from the default senses to be a decent answer. I did wonder about posting 'nonpareil' as it's pretty rare.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, *sui generis* is exactly right as the answer to the question considered in the abstract, even though it would not fit well the OP's sample sentence. It may nevertheless be worthile to post it as an answer, so that future visitors to the page can cinsider it on a par with other answers.

Comment: Why would you be unhappy with the Question's own title, 'unique thing'?

Answer (score 1):

If you were solver of crossword puzzles, your unique-thing noun would be *oner* (that’s pronounced one-er):

> **oner**, *n.*
> **1.** *slang.*
> **a.** A person or thing of a unique or remarkable kind; esp. a person who is particularly keen on or expert at something.
> <sub>[selected example]</sub>
>  <sub>1986     R. L.
> CHAPMAN *New Dict. Amer. Slang* (1987) 304/2     That was a
> great joke, a oner.</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

So: *This restaurant’s Loganberry Duck is one-of-a-kind, and the Crystal Brush Pulpo is another oner.*

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **rarity**. From [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rarity#Noun)

> 3. A rare object.

Some other possibilities are:

1. [wonder](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wonder#Noun) or [marvel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marvel#Noun), which I think don't imply uniqueness as much as you want.
2. [curiosity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curiosity#Noun) or [novelty](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/novelty#Noun), which I don't think are as positive as you want.
3. [delicacy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delicacy#Noun), which implies the food is expensive.
4. [original](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/original#Noun) implies uniqueness due to being invented by the restaurant while one-of-a-kind implies uniqueness due to quality

Answer (score 1):

***Exclusive*** as a noun refers to something that can only be obtained from one source. You'll often see this used in the context of journalism to refer to a story that is only available through one particular publication. It would be a somewhat unusual usage to use "exclusive" in this manner to refer to a dish with limited availability, but I think the context would be quite clear in the example sentence due to the juxtaposition with "one-of-a-kind".

> This restaurant's Loganberry Duck is one-of-a-kind, and the Crystal
> Brush Pulpo is another exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

The term that has been suggested by Mr. Baskin in a comment (within minutes of the posting of this question), ***sui generis***, answers perfectly the OP's general question ('What can I call a thing that is one-of-a-kind?'), although it does not fit well the OP's sample sentence. It would fit it syntactically if *another* were replaced with *also*, but it is debatable whether it would even then fit it pragmatically, as it is usually used in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

**One-off**. In your example sentence, you could say

> ...Crystal Brush Pulpo is another **One-off**.

(Although "one-of-a-kind" is not quite synonymous with "unique". **One-off** is usually for a unique *event* or *deed*, or an item like a 50th wedding anniversary cake, made only once).

In Collins Dictionary:

> 1. countable noun
>
> You can refer to something as a one-off when it is made or happens only once.
> [mainly British] ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/one-off))

Here is a use "in the wild":

> We feel that, as this is a one-off measure, it can help to promote job creation and to reduce the parallel economy. ([europarl.europa.eu](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT%20CRE%2020051201%20ITEMS%20DOC%20XML%20V0//EN&language=EN))

Comment: FWIW, I think this is the best of the options offered.

Answer (score 0):

**singleton**

> NOUN
> Something occurring or existing singly and not as one of a pair or of a group.
> (Webster's New World College Dictionary)

Comment: A singleton just implies that the item has no match or pair, it doesn't imply uniqueness. Shoes for one-legged people are singletons, but they're not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that it is **like no other.** [TFD defines this as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+no+other)

> Like nothing or no one else, as to highlight someone's or something's unique and important qualities.

Comment: You *could* say that, but that’s not a noun.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely say that something is ***unique to a place***:

> ***unique to somebody/something***
> existing only in a particular place or in relation to a particular person or people ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/unique-to-somebody-something))

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unique) defines the expression saying that:

> if something is ***unique to*** a place or situation, *it only exists in that place or situation*:
>
> - Many of our problems are ***unique to** our profession*.

So your sentence could be:

> This restaurant's Loganberry Duck is one-of-a-kind, and the Crystal Brush Pulpo is also ***unique to it/this place.***

Comment: You “can definitely” say that, but that’s not a noun.

Comment: @TinfoilHat The OP does not specify it should be a noun. Only in a comment there is mentioning of a noun. For lack of a suitable noun, this solution may be handy.

Comment: Read the title: *Noun for unique thing*.

Answer (score -1):

There's a word that fits semantically, but can sound rarefied:

> **nonpareil** [noun]:
>
> an unrivalled or matchless person or thing.
>
> - *a great player, Britain's nonpareil of the 1980s*.

[[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=nonpareil+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=nonpareil+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.2233876224j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

An example from the internet (the word in its adjective form ... which is more usual):

> - *Experience a nonpareil contemporary cafè with a fine dining twist in the heart of East Cantonments.*

[[Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/the_cassiagh/?hl=en-gb)]

And from [Rajesh Saxena, at Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-pareil-and-nonpareil-almonds):

> What is the meaning of *nonpareil*?
>
> The term "nonpareil" means "without equal" or "unsurpassed." It can be
> used to describe something or someone that is the best or most
> excellent of its kind. The word "nonpareil" comes from the French
> phrase "sans pareil", which means "without equal." The term is often
> used to describe people or things that are considered to be the best
> or most outstanding in their field or category. For example, someone
> might describe a sports team as a nonpareil, meaning that they are the
> best in their league, or a chef might be described as a nonpareil,
> meaning that they are the best in their profession.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe describing it as "particular" or "distinctive" to *that* place? There's also unrivaled, distinguished, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: None of these are nouns like the question is asking for.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest **epitome** for which [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epitome) has

> the typical or highest example of a stated quality, as shown by a particular person or thing

So for example

> This restaurant's Loganberry Duck is the **epitome** of how a roast should be.

Perhaps 'epitome' suggests 'epicure', and taking this idea further:

> This restaurant's Loganberry Duck is the **upper crust** of how a roast should be, and the Crystal Brush Pulpo is the **crème de la crème** of desserts.

Other suggestions are **quintessence** and **exemplification**.